# Read UTF-8 properties file and save as UTF-8 txt file

Tags: java, writer

I am currently trying to analyze all of my properties files and need my properties files in the form of a .txt file for one part. The problem is that german "Umlaute" like Ä,Ü,Ö etc. are not taken over correctly and therefore my program does not work. (If I convert the files manually into a txt there are no problems, but the whole thing should run dynamically)

Here is my code I am currently using:

```
private static void createTxt(String filePath, String savePath) throws IOException {
    final File file = new File(filePath);
    final BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
    final List<String> stringList= new ArrayList<>();
    String line = bReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
      stringList.add(line);
      line = bReader.readLine();
    }
    final Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(savePath), "UTF-8"));
    try {
      for (final String s : stringList) {
        out.write(s + "\n");
      }
    }
    finally {
      out.close();
    }
  }
```

The encoding of the txt is also UTF-8 - I think the problem is due to the bufferedReader or caching into the ArrayList

Thank you for your time and help, 
LG Pascal

Comment: Please write your questions in English here

Comment: Sorry I phrased my question in english now - thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading and writing files you should always set a charset. FileReader has a constructor that takes a Charset.

`new FileReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

If you just want to read all lines from a file just use `Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

To write you can use `Files.write(path, listOfStrings, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

And if you only want to copy the files, just use `Files.copy(source, target);`